# php-pdftk extension is not working on Windows

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm using Yii 2 and XAMPP on a Windows 7 Home Edition box and trying
to fill PDF form using [this extension](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk):

I've downloaded pdftk and installed it and the binaries `libiconf2.dll` and  `pdftk.exe` are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\`

Here is my code in controller (same as the sample provided in the above extension)

```
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

public function actionIndex()
{
    // Fill form with data array 
    $pdf = new Pdf('form.pdf');
    $pdf->fillForm(array('name'=>'John Doe'))
        ->needAppearances()
        ->saveAs('filled.pdf');
}
```

but it does not work. Nothing happens, absolutely nothing!

`form.pdf` file is in the webroot directory: `C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebsite\form.pdf`.

It seems, my php script cannot just find the pdftk binaries. I've tried to put them in the `vendor\bin directory` without any success.

As a newbie, I don't know where to place the pdftk binaries and / or whether there.

Are any other configurations steps I have to do?

Comment: Did you check for an error message? `$pdf->getError()`

Comment: Yes, I did and no error message is displayed.

Comment: This  <?php     
   exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" "C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebapplication\frontend\form.pdf" generate_fdf output formfields.fdf'); 
  ?>  works perfectly. So I think it could have something to do with  different file systens between Mac OS/unix and windows.

Comment: Did you really check for errors ? `var_dump($pdf->getError());`

Comment: var_dump($pdf->getError());

Comment: var_dump($pdf->getError());->string ''C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.' (length=99)

Comment: Error indicates that this might probably has got something to do with windows environment variables

Comment: Did you check you have "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin" in your path environnement var ?

Comment: Yes, because this command line instruction works perfectly: "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" form.pdf dump_data_fields > form-data-fields.txt

Comment: No, it should work without full path...

Comment: I have not tryed it yet without full path nor did I say it works only with full path. Could you please give me a sample of what you mean with "without full path"?

Comment: soju, your wright.  Replacing "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" in the above intruction by "path\pdftk.exe" does the job (path is my environment variable).  Une brillante idée!! Merci beacoup.